# Expected number of mafia in mafia game on any given day

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

The premise of the Mafia game goes like this:
There are a set of players (all residents) and they are divided into 2 groups, citizens and mafias. Each night mafias kill a member of the citizen and the following morning the residence lynch off one person. We assume the probability of lynching a mafia member and citizen are the same. So by this after each round there are 2 residents gone. 
What I am trying to do is calculate the expected number of mafia members on any given day. Is this possible if not can someone suggest an equally difficult problem in which I can do my research paper on.

[image]

Comment: You say, "After each round, there are two residents gone."  This doesn't sound like a matter of probability.  Assuming you mean "*at most* two residents gone" you'd need to tell us about the probabilities.  Even so, by linearity of expectation, the number of residents killed in the the first $n$ days is just the sum of the expectations for those days, so it doesn't sound very challenging.

Comment: For example there are 9 residents in total and 3 mafia. On day one there are 2/8 mafia members or 3/8 mafia members. On the second day there are   either 1/6 mafia members or 2/6 or 3/6 and so forth so it would be a tree diagram right? Presuming that how would you find probability as I tried and came up with an answer that is completely ridiculous.

Comment: You're right.  I missed the distinction between "citizen" and "resident" in the daytime killing.  Are you saying that the person lynched in the daytime is selected uniformly at random from the population?  That is, every person still alive has the same probability of being lynched?

Comment: Yes every person alive has the same probability of being lynched. Is there a way to calculate the number of mafia on a random given day?

Comment: I don't understand your example.  In the box at the top that says 3/14, Expected 9/14, what is 9/14 the expectation of?  Does the 3/14 mean 3 mafiosi out of a population of 14?

Comment: Yes it means that 3/14 is the probability of mafia members on the first day. I think 9/14 is 3*3/14 which means the expected number of mafia member which is 3 multiplied by the probability of that happening which is 3/14 am i right?

Comment: Yes, 9/14 is correct.  When you said "expected number of mafia members on a given day," I thought you meant the number remaining alive, not the number killed.  If that's what you mean, I suggest you edit the question.  I think my interpretation is the more natural one in English.

You can certainly do this with a tree diagram as you suggested.  I can't see a way to get a closed form formula off the top of my head, but I haven't thought about it much.  You should be able to get a recursive formula that you could evaluate by computer, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(m,t,d)$ be the expected number of mafia starting with $m$ mafia, $t$ town, and after $d$ days. Then, we have the following recursion
$$f(m,t,d) = \frac{t-1}{t+m - 1} f(m, t-2, d-1) + \frac{m}{t+m-1} f(m-1, t-1, d-1).$$

Our initial conditions are $f(m,t,0) = m, f(m, t, 1) = \frac{m(m+t-2)}{t+m-1}.$

I claim that
$$
f(m,t,d) = m \prod_{k = 1}^d  \frac{m+t - 2k}{m+t-2k+1}.
$$
We can check that this satisfies the initial conditions. Proving this formula is just induction.

This formula doesn't seem to work for edges cases though, like when the mafia kills off all of the town before day d.